# Тернарные операторы для тэгов С# html

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Такая ситуация: есть View, на которую выводится объект. В зависимости от значения некоторого поля объекта, необходимо выводить его в строку таблицы зелёным или чёрным цветом. Как можно сделать проверку в теге `<tr></tr>` не дублируя два варианта кода внутри тэга? Можно ли использовать для этой цели тернарные операторы?

Сейчас:

```
@if(ViewBag.Object.Property == 1)
{
    <tr style="color: #2e8b57;">...</tr>
}
else
{
    <tr>...</tr>
}
```

На месте символов **"..."** один и тот же код. Можно ли это как-то сделать стандартными средствами C#, без использования javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так:

```
<tr style='@(ViewBag.Object.Property == 1 ? "color: #2e8b57;" : "")'>...</tr>
```

А при чём тут вообще джаваскрипт?

Comment: спасибо огромное за ответ! Первый вариант кода работает, а второй - нет.

Comment: @cat_woman, потом гляну, что не так со вторым. Мне казалось, что должен работать. Пока удалю его из ответа.

Comment: Ок))) Спасибо ещё раз!))) Вы спасли мою жизнь!)))

Comment: а что обозначает оператор ViewBag.Object.Name ?? "" и можно ли его использовать вместо выражения ViewBag.Object.Name != null ? ViewBag.Object.Name : "" ?

Comment: @cat_woman, вот именно его он и означает.

Comment: на сколько я понимаю, в большом количестве проверки сильно тормозят отображение view, однако, без них никак нельзя. Есть ли какой-то способ ускорить отображение view?

Comment: @cat_woman, ничего не понял.